# Azure Functions Core Tools v3.0.2009 "func init" no longer creates project file

Tags: azure-functions

I have removed the earlier version of Azure Function Core Tools and installed the version 3 by running

`npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3`

After the update i can create Azure functions v3 from both VS2019 and VS Code but CLI no longer creates the project file.

Previously i was able to run `func init PROJECTNAME` and it was creating the full folder structure with .csproj file which i could use later on with VS Code or VS2019 but this is no longer working for me.

I have NodeJs v12.14.0

I have func version 3.0.2009

I have azure client version 2.0.79

Here is the result when i issue func init

`c:\temp>func init FunctionApp3`

`Select a worker runtime: dotnet`

`Writing c:\temp\FunctionApp3\.vscode\extensions.json`

c:\temp

No errors

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks to Murat Kazanova for his efforts. The problem still seems to be related to the npm installation, which is the similar as what I have encountered before. In order to make it easier for people who encounter this problem in the future to get rid of this problem, I post here other efforts made by Murat Kazanova. Besides trying npm reinstall, you should also try performed npm cleanup, reinstalled azure client tools and updated vs studio with azure tools.

**Original Answer:**

Please reinstall the function core tools and restart your computer. I face this problem before(cannot create the project I set, only create some json files and other files), but after that operate this problem disappear. Have a try on your side.:)

Comment: I've already done that so many times but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: @MuratKazanova Hi, MuratKazanova. Still have that problem?

Comment: It seems like it is working for now but honestly I don’t know what really worked. I tried many things.

Comment: @MuratKazanova Congratulations anyway on getting rid of this problem, what efforts have you made?

Comment: I’ve uninstalled and reinstalled many times, Performed npm cleanup, reinstalled azure client tools and updated vs studio with azure tools

Comment: @MuratKazanova Thanks for your contribution, I updated my answer, can you mark it as an answer to end this question? It will help others who meet the similar question.If there are better answers in the future, you can re mark.:)